# Poured boiling water over pork belly and then refrigerated

Tags: food-safety

I read about a method of preparing pork belly in the below article that involved pouring boiling water over the rind of belly pork, then refrigerating it over night(so it has a chance to dry before cooking). It's supposed to make the crackling nicer.
http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2010/apr/15/how-to-make-perfect-crackling

I placed the pork belly slab in a roasting tray in the sink and poured boiling water over it from a kettle. It was in a pool of boiled water for a good 10 seconds before i managed to lift it out(I didn't think this through properly). It looked like the outside of the meat was starting to cook, but I'm not sure if this is the case or not.

I then placed it in the fridge in some marinade, where it will sit over night.

I plan on cooking it tomorrow at 200C(fan oven) for 30mins, then 160C for 2-3 hours. but I'm worried. Will we be at risk of food poisoning?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's recommended that you limit your questions to one topic only rather than asking multiple questions in one. To answer your second question, [this answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/30257/33128) should be helpful to you, so I'm going to remove the second question from your question body.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the marinade itself was room temperature or cooler, I wouldn't worry about it. The cooked/heated portions of the belly will chill quickly enough.